Can an exhaust vent be mounted directly to wall sheathing instead of a trim plate?
I'm installing a kitchen hood vent and I'm wondering what the best practices are here for mounting the exhaust vent to the exterior wall.

The dimensions of the exhaust vent are 9 3/4" vertically and 8.5" wide. The kitchen vent hood manufacturer recommends making a mounting plate using PVC trim for mounting the exhaust vent:

Make the mounting plate
Cut the PVC trim to match the size and shape of the wall cap. Then, cut a hole in the PVC trim that is the same size as the duct hole. This will be your mounting plate.


The problem is the only available PVC trim that would fit the exhaust vent dimensions is an expensive 3/4"x10"x8' PVC trim.
And I only need a small cut of it. I also don't have a table or miter saw just yet, and Lowes won't cut plastic, so I'd have to rely on a hand saw for any cuts.
My question here is whether it's really necessary to add a mounting plate for the exhaust vent, or can I mount it directly to the OSB (caulk + screws), and then cover the mounting screws with wooden trim around the exterior of the vent, of course properly sealed with caulking and z-flashing? Should the PVC trim be the exact size of the exhaust vent, or slightly larger?
If I do go the mounting plate route, this means the screws on the exhaust vent will now be showing, unless I add a decorative trim or frame around that as well, like this guy does. I will be painting the vent to match the color of the hardieplank siding, to help everything blend in either way.
Is it standard to add both a mounting plate and a decorative frame?
For a decorative frame, is 3/4"x1.5" sufficient?

There's no reason you can't forego the trim plate, but recognize its purpose: To allow weather sealing in the siding, and not to your vent. The vent shouldn't be part of your building envelope, strictly speaking, and if you root it in place like that you can't easily replace it or remove it for access or whatever.
Do as you see fit as long as you have a good drainage strategy and can tolerate the implications of your arrangement.

Thanks for the response. Any idea how thick a trim plate should be? The hardiplank sits 3/4" off the sheathing at it's thickest point.

Well, thicker than that, then, so you have something to caulk to. Please take the [tour] so  you know how to respond to answers.

Because you have a solid siding, you need a siding block that sits on the surface, or you need to inset and weatherproof a trim plate into a matching hole you cut in the siding.  Here's a siding block example: https://amp.architecturaldepot.com/130110007085.html
